# submenu background hidden behind video css

Tags: html, css, video

My sub menu background radius hidden behind the video. I have tried "wmode=transparent" and z-index properties. But nothing works. How to fix this?

Html:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">mainmenu</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">submenu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/v/v73Aj6XqHOg?wmode=transparent" wmode="transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

css:

```
#nav li ul {
position:absolute; z-index:1000;
display:none; width:147px; padding:0px; margin:0px;
top:1.8em; background-color:#d1d1d1; 
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px 5px;
moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px 5px; line-height:15px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:3px;
moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px 5px;

}
```

[image]

Left image is the error and right one is the needed result. Any help?

Comment: May not be an issue, but I think putting non-prefix properties after prefixed ones would be better. Also `moz-border...` might be `-moz-border...`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wLqk2/ Seems no problem in my Chrome 27.

Comment: @Passersby - It's not working fine with other browsers like mozilla

Comment: The Mozilla equivalent is the following: `-moz-border-radius-bottomleft` as described here: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/border-radius/#.Ud1UgG2j_75. I've tried it, but the issue still exists.